# How to attach files from html to gmail or yahoo mail?

Tags: php, mysql, gmail

I build local aplication with PHP and MYSQL (it mean I dont have mail Server)
  is it possible from local files uploaded directly to gmail or yahoo mail? is hard to say, i Will give a sample I Have PHP file like this

[image]

I want, if I clik send to email link, it automatic open the google mail or yahoo mail  and the upload addres fill automatic on the input file.

like this
[image]

whether it is possible to be done, and how the solution?

Im Very Appreciated from your advice.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just send them a link to where you host the image?

Comment: @zjd I Built in local server,not use hosting :)

Comment: Why not just host it? http://byethost.com/free-hosting